# Returning wrong MD5 hash in C

Tags: c, string, hash, md5

I am trying to generate MD5 hash for an string *"Hello World"* using the original/untouched md5.h and [md5c.c](http://www.arp.harvard.edu/eng/das/manuals/QNX6libs/md5c_8c_source.html) from http://www.arp.harvard.edu. But my result differs from all md5 online tools i have tested. Whats wrong this this code? Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "md5.h"

void MD5hash(unsigned char *data, unsigned int dataLen, unsigned char *digest) {
    MD5_CTX c;
    MD5Init(&c);
    MD5Update(&c, data, dataLen);
    MD5Final(digest, &c);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    unsigned char digest[16];
    const char *s = "Hello World";
    unsigned int l = (unsigned int)strlen(s);

    MD5hash((unsigned char *)s, l, digest);
    for(int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
         printf("%02x", digest[i]);
    return 0;
}

// My result: f2877a72c40494318c4b050bb436c582
// But online tools output: b10a8db164e0754105b7a99be72e3fe5
```

Comment: As a side note - I have compiled your code against OpenSSL's MD5 implementation - it works as expected! So indeed `md5.c` you try to use may simply be broken one way or another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an issue with padding. The MD5 Hash algorithm works on 512-bit blocks. When your final block is less than 512 bits, it needs to be padded. In your example, the first block is also the last block because it's less than 512 bits.

The padding is format is called [Merkle–Damgård construction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle%E2%80%93Damg%C3%A5rd_construction).

You can find some pseudo code that includes padding [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Pseudocode).

Comment: Isn't `MD5Finalize()` supposed to perform all the necessary padding?

Comment: @vipw, you're right. i will try it later (my kid is crying now at home). Thanks.

Comment: Just my curiosity - why this answer was accepted, while ouah's answer is much better?

Comment: @CodePainters looks like he accepted too soon, before testing it.

Answer (score 5):

As @vipw mentioned there is an issue with padding. This MD5 implementation does not correctly manage padding for message sizes that are not a multiple of a MD5 block size (512-bit / 64 bytes).

To fix it on your side, replace:

```
const char *s = "Hello World";
```

by

```
const char s[64] = "Hello World";
```

**EDIT**:

There was a second issue related to portability in this MD5 implementation. In `md5.h` there is this type alias:

```
typedef unsigned long int UINT4;
```

On a Linux x86_64 system (which you are using), this must be changed to this:

```
typedef unsigned int UINT4;
```

Comment: How is that supposed to change anything? The `MD5_Update()` would process `strlen(s)` bytes anyway.

Comment: Does any function modify `s` though? Are you implying that this program invokes undefined behaviour?

Comment: @CodePainters apparently the implementation is broken and read more than the length you pass in `dataLen`.

Comment: @CodePainters I suggest you to try this, it will fix your issue.

Comment: @CodePainters hmm, it did on my side, just tried. Let me check further.

Comment: I simply can hardly believe in such a badly broken MD5 implementation ;-)

Comment: @CodePainters I retried and that was the issue. Are you sure you only modified the line I suggested? (For example the `strlen` line should not change.)

Comment: Note there can be other issues with endianness or 32 / 64 -bit on top of that;)

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure. What platform you're testing on? It's x86_64 Linux for me.

Comment: Trying on a x86_64 Linux I have now the same result as you. Looks like this MD5 implementation is not portable.

Comment: OK I found the second issue: the typedef `UINT4` in `md5.h` should be update to `unsigned int` for x86_64 Linux.

Comment: Or you could use the portable types in `stdint.h`, `uint32_t` will always be four bytes.

Comment: is there any fixes available for this issue ?