# MD5 of string gives wrong output in C

Tags: c, hash, openssl, cryptography, md5

My question is similar to [this one here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15875569/returning-wrong-md5-hash-in-c) but I'm using openssl/md5.h

I'm trying to get user input and find its MD5 hash. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/md5.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void MD5hash(unsigned char *data, unsigned int dataLen, unsigned char *digest) {
    MD5_CTX c;
    MD5_Init(&c);
    MD5_Update(&c, data, dataLen);
    MD5_Final(digest, &c);
}

int main(){
    unsigned char md5_hash[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    char *input = NULL;
    int i, read;
    size_t len; 

    printf("Enter the password: ");
    read = getline(&input, &len, stdin);

    unsigned int str_length = (unsigned int)strlen(input);
    if(-1 != read)
        puts(input);
    else
        printf("Received no input\n");

    printf("Size read: %d Len: %zu String Length: %u\n", read, len, str_length);

    MD5hash((unsigned char *)input, str_length, md5_hash);

    printf("MD5 hash is: ");
    for(i = 0; i < MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++){
        printf("%02x", md5_hash[i]);
    } 
    printf("\n");
    free(input);

    return 0;
}
```

This code compiles and runs successfully on my Mac. When I give `12345` as input to the binary, the output I get is `d577273ff885c3f84dadb8578bb41399`:

```
 $ ./md5code
 Enter the password: 12345
 12345

 Size read: 6 Len: 8
 String Length: 6
 MD5 hash is: d577273ff885c3f84dadb8578bb41399
```

However, when I run `md5 -s 12345`, the output I get is `827ccb0eea8a706c4c34a16891f84e7b` which is also the output I get when I check the MD5 using online tools.

My initial thoughts were that this is because of the NULL terminator so I calculated the MD5 of the string with them:

```
$ md5 -s 12345
MD5 ("12345") = 827ccb0eea8a706c4c34a16891f84e7b
$md5 -s "12345\0"
MD5 ("12345\0") = b04fd4a8d62d25c4b69616ba7f5c5092
$md5 -s 12345\0
MD5 ("123450") = 149787a6b7986f31b3dcc0e4e857cd2a
$md5 -s "12345 "
MD5 ("12345 ") = 43d6757765116456c1c49310cbf8070d
$ md5 -s "12345\n"
MD5 ("12345\n") = 5d44fc965c76c70d2ebe72b4129bc0cd
```

As you can see, none of the MD5s match the one that I'm getting from my code. Can anyone help me figure out what is wrong and how to fix it? Thanks!

**Note:** I'm well aware that MD5 is a very weak and broken hash and should not be used for any real purposes. I'm doing this just to understand basic coding.

Comment: I think you may have a newline issue. `getline` should leave the newline in the returned string.

Comment: Check if getline(&input, &len, stdin); isn't storing the new line character when you hit enter. And it is getting processed as part of the digest.

Comment: `getline` is including the newline, which you're apparently not expecting (nor desiring) to be included in your md5 source data. Ten seconds in a debugger and inspecting the `input` string will confirm that. Not including the newline (i.e. using `str_length-1` as the argument to you function delivers `827ccb0eea8a706c4c34a16891f84e7b` as it should.

Comment: @MFisherKDX - Good point! I checked the output of `md5 -s "12345\n"` and updated the question with it. The hash I get is `5d44fc965c76c70d2ebe72b4129bc0cd` which is still not the same as the hash from my code.

Comment: @WhozCraig - Thanks! That was helpful. If you post this as answer, I can accept it as the answer that helped me. Could you also please include the method that you used for debugging or include link to it? I'm familiar with debuggers but I'm not very familiar with the debugging process itself.

Comment: @Throwaway Account - Calling `md5 -s "12345\n"` on the shell won't put a newline-character after `12345`. But put the two characters  "\"  and "n" at the end of the string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the output these two OpenSSL commands (which you can also replace with `openssl dgst -md5` commands to get the same output):

```
$ md5 <(echo 12345)
MD5 (/dev/fd/63) = d577273ff885c3f84dadb8578bb41399
$ md5 <(printf 12345)
MD5 (/dev/fd/63) = 827ccb0eea8a706c4c34a16891f84e7b
```

The latter one is the one you are looking for. The difference between `echo` and `printf` is that the former adds a newline and the latter does not:

```
$ hexdump -C <(echo 12345)
00000000  31 32 33 34 35 0a                                 |12345.|
00000006
$ hexdump -C <(printf 12345)
00000000  31 32 33 34 35                                    |12345|
00000005
```

So it is the `0a` that is causing you the troubles.

Two additional remarks: the `<(echo 12345)` construct is an example of [Process Substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) and instead of `printf`, you can also use `echo -n`. The latter is not standardized though, as pointed out in a comment below.

Comment: You could also just use a pipe, with or without printf (but i'd definitely use printf.)

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I prefer the way process substitution looks tough (today at least). Out of curiosity, why would you _definitely use `printf`_?

Comment: Because printf is standardized. If you use `echo -n` you are at the mercy of a non-standard extension in a particular shell, which you may well find does not work in the next shell you use. Process substitution is painfully hard to chain, but it's certainly your choice. My desktop history is full of pipe chains.

Comment: OK, thanks for explaining, good motivation. Sufficient reason for me to revert `echo -n` back to `printf`, like I had it initially.